# Prevent multiple $.ready() functions from triggering at once?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working on making a small advertisement script.

An ad is inserted on a page, by inserting the following script:

```
<script class="gd-ad-script" src="http://domain.dk/ads/gdAds.js?adID=1&x=auto&y=auto&loadAd=?"></script>
<script class="gd-ad-script" src="http://domain.dk/ads/gdAds.js?adID=2&x=auto&y=auto&loadAd=?"></script>
<script class="gd-ad-script" src="http://domain.dk/ads/gdAds.js?adID=3&x=auto&y=auto&loadAd=?"></script>
```

This should insert 3 ads on the page. Since the adID is set, it should not select a random ad, but a specific ad.

Now here is my script:

```
/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
// * jQuery libary here * //


$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;

var JSONurl = 'http://domain.dk/ads/loadAd.php?callback=?';

$('.gd-ad-script').each(function(){

    var adSrc = $(this).attr('src');

    var adID = adSrc.substring(adSrc.indexOf('?adID=') + 6, adSrc.indexOf('&x='));
    var x = adSrc.substring(adSrc.indexOf('&x=') + 3, adSrc.indexOf('&y='));
    var y = adSrc.substring(adSrc.indexOf('&y=') + 3, adSrc.indexOf('&loadAd=?'));

    var JSONdata = 'domain=' + window.location.hostname + '&adID=' + adID + '&xres=' + x + '&yres=' + y;

    $(this).attr('id', 'add-current-ad' + adID);

    $.getJSON(JSONurl, JSONdata, function(serverResponse) {
        ++count;
        if (count == 1) {
            alert(adID); // Comment this line out, unless testing
            $('head').prepend(serverResponse.cssReset);
            $(serverResponse.adContent).insertAfter('#add-current-ad' + adID);
            $('#add-current-ad' + adID).remove();
        }
    });

});

});
```

Now, I would expect the page with the three scripts on, giving med three alert boxes in sequential order. 1, 2, 3.
However, it is completely random because it all depends on how fast the server response from my ajax call is.

The results is, that the ads are placed in random order instead of 1, 2, 3.

My first thought was to use .gd-ad-script:first as selector, so that each script would process only one ad but then I realized that it would require me to somehow delay everything until the first ad script is removed, which is undesirable...

Any good advices?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order wrong is because your script is not doing what you think it's doing.

You are including your script three times with different GET parameters.

(NB: This will cause the browser the download the script three times from the server, which is unnecessary, because it's the same script each time. )

Unless I'm missing something (which could be, because what you are doing with the `count` variable seems quite confusing), all three time your script runs, it loops over all three  `<script>` elements leading them all to process the same first `<script>` element, because there is nothing that allows them to identify the `<script>` elements that have already been processed.

IMHO you should rethink your whole concept:

- Make sure your script is only downloaded once.
- **Either** run it three times, each processing its own ad and not looping over all **or** run it once looping over all ads.
- Make sure you attach your ads after the correct elements. That way the order the AJAX request comeback shouldn't matter.

Personally I wouldn't include the script three times, but only once, and mark the postions of the ads with some other element. Something like this:

```
<script src="http://domain.dk/ads/gdAds.js"></script>
<div data-ad-id="1" data-ad-x="auto" data-ad-y="auto"></div>
<div data-ad-id="2" data-ad-x="auto" data-ad-y="auto"></div>
<div data-ad-id="3" data-ad-x="auto" data-ad-y="auto"></div>
```

with (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var JSONurl = 'http://domain.dk/ads/loadAd.php?callback=?';


    $('[data-ad-id]').each(function(){

        var ad = $(this);
        var adID = ad.data('ad-id');
        var x = ad.data('ad-x');
        var y = ad.data('ad-y');

        var JSONdata = 'domain=' + window.location.hostname + '&adID=' + adID + '&xres=' + x + '&yres=' + y;

        $.getJSON(JSONurl, JSONdata,
            (function(ad) {
                    function(serverResponse) {
                        $('head').prepend(serverResponse.cssReset);
                    $(serverResponse.adContent).insertAfter(ad);
                    ad.remove();
                }
            })(ad) 
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi RoToRa... Thanks for your answer. I have thought of that myself, however the inserting ads onto a page should be as simple as possible (e.g. a widget in Wordpress) and I can not rely on the person adding the ad, have know-how to insert a script in the head or understand where to place. However I have found a fix myself, but rearrangeing the order of adding/removing elements. I'll post it later :)